# Google Cloud Datastore - Scalability of indexing a short list of enums

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Is it an issue in Datastore to index a property that can only have 4-5 possible values? Would this lead to tablet hotspots?

I am thinking of a property with an enum of string values like "done", "working", "complete". The reason for indexing such a property would be so you can create a composite index that let's you query on all entities that are "done" for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would be an issue if/when you have high rates of queries using these composite indexes you mentioned, listed in [Indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#indexes):

> - Do not index properties with monotonically increasing values (such as a `NOW()` timestamp). Maintaining such an index could lead to
>     hotspots that impact Cloud Datastore latency for applications with
>     high read and write rates. For further guidance on dealing with
>     monotonic properties, see [High read/write rates for a narrow key
>     range](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#high_readwrite_rates_to_a_narrow_key_range) below.

You would also have a tablet hotspot problem if/when you hit high rates of datastore writes for entities with the same property value (for example 100s of entities becoming `done` per second) - another facet of the same problem. It's this case mentioned in [High read/write rates to a narrow key range](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#high_readwrite_rates_to_a_narrow_key_range):

> - You will also see this problem if you create new entities at a high rate with a monotonically increasing indexed property like a
>     timestamp, because these properties are the keys for rows in the index
>     tables in Bigtable.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: It scales so long as entity keys are scattered.

DR:

Lets first consider the index entries being written.

We have something like:

```
SomeKind\E1 -> FullEntityKey1
SomeKind\E2 -> FullEntityKey2
SomeKind\E2 -> FullEntityKey3
SomeKind\E3 -> FullEntityKey4
```

We note that each individual index entry points to some entity.

As far as the load sharding is concerned the value being sharded is like the following:

```
SomeKind\E1\FullEntityKey1
SomeKind\E2\FullEntityKey2
SomeKind\E2\FullEntityKey3
SomeKind\E3\FullEntityKey4
```

Now lets imagine we were using randomly allocated ids for the entity keys (range [0,2] to be simple) -- we assume even distribution of writes across the random entity ids.

```
SomeKind\E1\0\RestOfKey1
SomeKind\E2\0\RestOfKey2
SomeKind\E2\1\RestOfKey3
SomeKind\E3\2\RestOfKey4
```

And then we can note that there are clear split points for the load to shard across -- that is every of the [0,2] possible random ids is a shard and the system can scale indefinitely so long as the writes are evenly distributed across the enties in SomeKind written (make the random id longer for more split points/scaling)

So the is index enum value scaling/hotspotting is highly associated with the entity keys being indexed, which are generally constructed in ways that are shardable which means that the associated index entries also are.

This is not to say that it is impossible to create situations in which [hotspots](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#high_readwrite_rates_to_a_narrow_key_range) may occur (for example, if the entity keys had a monotonically increasing value (like a timestamp)), or by targeting a small section of keys for a very high write rate -- but that shouldn't happen by default with typical traffic patterns and entity keys.

Comment: I'm wondering at scale however, like when an application has a lot of read/writes (think worst case). So it looks like from what you say, there could be hotspots in my example?

Comment: It would be hard to get hotspots - you have to be doing something else wrong -- the indexing pattern suggested doesn't cause hotspots by itself.